# oauth error: (Couldn't connect to server) in oauth getRequestToken method

Tags: php, oauth

I asked this question once time in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12814603/ but i do not know why my question closed!

I found my answer and i would like to share it, now.

**Question**

I have a script to send invitation email to web-mail services.

But now, I get error without any change to the code. When I run script, the browser status bar shown "`Waiting for domain.com`"

And after several seconds I give following error in `oauth->getRequestToken`:

> making the request failed (Couldn't connect to server)

I want to know why this error occur or what are the reasons to happen this error? Dose it related to firewall (csf) settings (e.g. Blocked port and etc.)?

NOTE: I do not any change in my code when it works or now.

PHP 5.2.17 CentOS 6.2 oauth last released

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my question I said i am using **csf** firewall and asked `Dose it related to firewall (csf) settings (e.g. Blocked port and etc.)?`

My csf firewall was blocked Google and Yahoo IPs.

The problem solved after i added Yahoo and Google IPs to `Allow IPs` in csf firewall setting.

Just put following IPs:

```
173.194.0.0/16 # Google
77.0.0.0/8 # Yahoo
```